# Upload multiple files at the same time without a duplicate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, random

I use this code to upload multiple files together in Laravel. However, all name files get duplicated. Please guide me.

```php
if (is_array($files) || is_object($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $name = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path('uploadmusic'), $name);

        PostPhoto::create([
            'post_id' => $post->id,
            'filename' => $name
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

```
1568314601.png
1568314601.png
1568314601.png
```

Comment: the description is not clear enough. what do you want to do exactly? why don't you use `Storage` Class for storing files? does file names are needed for further usage or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision of [`time()`](https://www.php.net/time) is only a second - not enough time to make `time()` report a different value when assigning `$name` in your loop for each file.

Append something else, like a call to `\Illuminate\Support\Str::random()` to get each name to be unique.

Depending on requirements, you might consider omitting the timestamp from the filename altogether and use something like [`md_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) instead.

```
$name = implode('.', [
    md5_file($file->getPathname()),
    $file->getClientOriginalExtension()
]);
```

This can also help keep duplicate files off of your storage device.